# Java : what debug to add to find what caused a process to hang

Tags: java, multithreading

Running code that is processing a large amount of data in a Loop.
Throughout the loop timestamps are printed to a Log file.

```
For LOOP
{
    Timestamp 1  - Start of Loop
        :
        :
    Timestamp 2
        :
        :
    Timestamp 3
        :
        :
    Timestamp 4
        :
        :
    Timestamp 5 - END of Loop
}
```

The delay can be anywhere from 2 seconds to 14 seconds between Timestamp when it should take milliseconds.

At some spots the delay occurs when simply setting primitive variables.

The strangest delay seen is going from Timestamp 5 to Timestamp 1 when it simply transition from the bottom to top of the Loop.

The location of the delays are sporadic and even set the JVM from a minimum size of 512M to 1024M but this had no affect what so ever.

I was going to use JVisualVM but this is an AIX machine with JRE 1.6 and I could not find a JVisualVM to download for AIX.

Is there any debug that can be added to uncover what could be causing such a significant delay?

Comment: why is this tagged with multithreading? is this loop executed in several threads at the same time?

Comment: My thinking is this is part of a larger application which has numerous threads. Since I can not phantom anything specific in this code being the issue, my hypothesis is some other thread has caused this one to pause due to such lengthy delays.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, turning on garbage collection tracing showed a significant delay which matched with the timestamp of the delay occurring within the application.